# How to stop ggplot from getting smaller due to an added index in the title?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, gridextra

My Problem is, that i have a gridarrange object out of 6 Scatterplots with 3 different titels. The 2nd title has in index number, which makes my plot slightly smaller. Is there a way to prevent that from happening?

My code is:

```
   a<- ggplot(data=Bad_Lauchstaedt, mapping=aes(x= `one_h_gap_ET0`, y= `BL 2-1`))+
  geom_smooth(method = "lm",se=FALSE, color="red")+
  geom_point(color="darkblue", shape=1)+
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1, color="black", size=1.2, linetype="twodash")+
  labs(y="measured data", x="gap filled data by lysimeters", title = expression("ET"[0]))+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 20))+
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),axis.text.x = element_blank(),axis.ticks.x = element_blank())+
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(),axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.ticks.y = element_blank())+
  xlim(0,0.9)+
  ylim(0,0.9)+
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0,0,0,0),"pt"))+
   geom_richtext(
     data = b_label,
     aes(posx, posy, label = label),
     hjust = 0, vjust = 0,
     size = 6,
     fill = "white", label.color = "black")


    scatterplots<- list(a,b,c,d,e,f)
    grobs= lapply(scatterplots, ggplotGrob)
    
    grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(grobs=scatterplots, widths= c(1,1,1), 
                             layout_matrix = rbind(c(1,2,3),
                                                   c(4,5,6))),
                left=grid::textGrob('hourly ET observed [mm]', gp=grid::gpar(fontsize=18), rot= 90), 
                 bottom=grid::textGrob('hourly ET gap filled [mm]', gp=grid::gpar(fontsize=18)),
                 top = grid::textGrob('gap filled by', gp=grid::gpar(fontsize=24)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe consider not using grid.arrange...

patchwork or cowplot are much easier (although this may be subjective) and maybe safer. Way less code as well.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

p_norm <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_point() +
  ggtitle("normal")
p_abnorm <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_point() +
  ggtitle(expression("ET"[0]))
wrap_plots(c(list(p_norm, p_abnorm), rep(list(p_norm), 4)))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

so the index of ET 0 , created by

```
title = expression("ET"[0]))
```

f** s up your alignment of the plots.

[image]

my suggestet (somewhat hacky) quickfix is to add:

```
title = expression("normal title"[]))
```

to all other titles.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I just did the same now. Probably not the prettiest solution but it solves the problem.

Comment: it's usually nice to have code to reproduce this with. This would also include the plots that you have generated.